# Entity Framework - Determining if a Relationship Exists without a navigation property on one end

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following two entities (using Code First) in my application:

```
public class Note
{
    public int NoteId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Decision 
{
    // PK/FK
    public int NoteId { get; set; }

    // other fields ...

    public virtual Note Note { get; set; }
}
```

I configured my relationship like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Decision>().HasRequired(d => d.Note).WithOptional();
```

A Decision must have a note but a Note does not always have a decision. A 1:1 mapping with one side being optional.

I would like a property on my note that lets me know if there is a decision for it. Something like:

```
public bool HasDecision 
{
    get
    {
        // not sure what to do here
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having Decision be a lazy loaded property on Note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do an explicite query. There is no such thing like "lazy loading proxies for scalar properties". Lazy loading is only supported for navigation properties. Your entity must have a reference to a context if you want to have `HasDecision` as a property on the entity. I would prefer to create a repository or service method like so:

```
public bool HasDecision(Note note)
{
    return _context.Decisions.Any(d => d.NoteId == note.NoteId);
}
```

Comment: I figured I might end up having to just create a repository/service method for this, but I wondered if it was possible to do on the entity itself. It is probably not advisable to just pass a reference to your context to an entity correct?

Comment: @Dismissile: Yes, in my opinion it's not advisable: 1) because of the idea of POCO entities in general which are supposed to be "persistence ignorant", and 2) because of a possible different lifetime of POCOs and context: You could inject a context into an entity and then later dispose the context. Using your property then (= issueing a query) would throw an exception. Well, the latter is also true for lazily loaded navigation properties.

Comment: The lifetime issue isn't really a problem in my opinion, since my context is for the lifetime of the request, but I do agree that they should probably not be having any reference to the context at all. Thanks for your input.